# Newbie question. Guess a number - code not working

Tags: python, random

```
    import random

    def guess(x):
random_number = random.randint(1, x)
guess = 0
while guess != random_number:
    guess = int(input(f"Guess a number between 1 and {x}: "))
    if guess > random_number:
        print(f"{guess} is incorrect, try lower!")
    elif guess < random_number:
        print(f"{guess} is incorrect, try higher!")


print(f"congratulations, you have guessed {random_number} correctly!")
```

Please help with this code, I have no idea why it's just not working. Been trying for a few hours. I see no issue with it, but then again, I am a newbie.

Comment: Please, format the code properly. In Python, correct indentation is crucial. The other point is that you have declared a function, but you are not calling it anywhere

Comment: "code not working" doesn't help us understand what problems you're facing. It's helpful to say exactly what's going wrong. Are you getting an exception? (If so, show the whole exception, including the traceback.) Are you getting behaviour you didn't expect? (If so, describe the behaviour you're getting and the behaviour you expected to get.)  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for some advice.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works correctly -

```py
import random


def guess(x):
    random_number = random.randint(1, x)
    guess = 0
    while guess != random_number:
        guess = int(input(f"Guess a number between 1 and {x}: "))
        if guess > random_number:
            print(f"{guess} is incorrect, try lower!")
        elif guess < random_number:
            print(f"{guess} is incorrect, try higher!")

    print(f"congratulations, you have guessed {random_number} correctly!")


def main():
    guess(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The only change is that the function is called. In python, a function must be called in order to run. In the code you have provided, the function was declared, but until someone "uses" it, it will just be a definition of the function.
In the code I have added, I call the function using `guess(2)`. You may use it with other parameters :)

Please note that a big potential bug in the code is the fact the you use a variable with the same name of the function. This is a very bad idea and may cause many issues.
So a fix for this would be to change the variable `guess` to something like `current_guess`.

So here it would be -

```py
import random


def guess(x):
    random_number = random.randint(1, x)
    current_guess = 0
    while current_guess != random_number:
        current_guess = int(input(f"Guess a number between 1 and {x}: "))
        if current_guess > random_number:
            print(f"{current_guess} is incorrect, try lower!")
        elif current_guess < random_number:
            print(f"{current_guess} is incorrect, try higher!")

    print(f"congratulations, you have guessed {random_number} correctly!")


def main():
    guess(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```